# Refactoring tools for namespaces and physical project structure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, namespaces, physical-design

When I hack around, some code tend to get much bigger than originally planned. As this happens I usually introduce/collapse/merge namespaces, move files between them, move folders etc etc. Sometimes, if I don't have a clear picture of the end result, this is a real pain and really easy to just "skip". This leads the project deteriorate where classes belong elsewhere, strange namespaces, no folders/wrong folders etc.
And then I usually cannot take it anymore and do a larger cleanup - which is usually not difficult, just very tedious and it feels nice to do everything at once, so I do a code freeze while finishing up.

So my question is... Are there any tools to help refactoring the namespace/physical aspects of a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most popular refactoring tools for Visual Studio are [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [Code Rush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/).

Also see [Resharper vs. CodeRush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/resharper-vs-coderush).

Comment: I've had good experiences using the Resharper tools for changing namespaces and folders.  It cleanly updates dependencies across all projects in the solution.

Comment: I'm using CodeRush already and love it. But still, I'm missing some refactoring - unless I'm overlooking something. Just a couple of things would help a lot:
 * Move class to namespace
 * Rename namespace

Comment: I am not extremely versed in CodeRush, but it is possible to rename a namespace with Resharper (I just tried it and had no issues).

Comment: Didn't catch that last previous comment. Checked ReSharper again, and it seems they have some of these features.

Comment: No open source alternatives exist?